# release vs setting-to-nil to free memory

Tags: objective-c, iphone, memory-management

In my root view controller, in my didReceiveMemoryWarning method, I go through a couple data structures (which I keep in a global singleton called DataManager), and ditch the heaviest things I've got--one or maybe two images associated with possibly twenty or thirty or more data records.

Right now I'm going through and setting those to nil. I'm also setting myself a boolean flag so that various view controllers that need this data can easily know to reload. Thusly:

```
DataManager *data = [DataManager sharedDataManager];
for (Event *event in data.eventList) {
    event.image = nil;
    event.thumbnail = nil;
}

for (WondrMark *mark in data.wondrMarks) {
    mark.image = nil;
}

[DataManager sharedDataManager].cleanedMemory = YES;
```

Today I'm thinking, though... and I'm not actually sure all that allocated memory is really being freed when I do that. Should I instead `release` those images and maybe hit them with a new `alloc` and `init` when I need them again later?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting an instance variable directly, as mipadi says, does not release the object it refers to. What you're doing here is different, though: you're setting the value of object's property. Depending on how that property is declared, that may indeed be releasing the value it refers to. A property declared `retain` or `copy`, rather than `assign`, gets a synthesized accessor method (the `setImage:` method that the `.image =` syntax translates to) that releases its old value when setting a new one. So, in this case, if your `WondrMark`'s property is declared as `retain`, setting it to nil—via the property—does automatically release the old image. If it's `assign`, you need to release the image before setting the property to nil.

Comment: Killer. I lucked into the right solution, it turns out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Objects are not freed when you set them to `nil`, so yes, you should release them.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be directly releasing other objects' instance variables or properties. Those objects are responsible for doing so themselves.

However, if can object releases its instance variables when a new one is set (such as with `retain` properties), then setting the instance variable to nil will have cause the object to release the old value.