# Re-instantiate an object and memory leaks

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm wondering what the safest way is to release an object and Re-instantiate it again.

What I'm doing is this and it seems to work but I'm not sure if this is not creating a memory leak ?

```
- (void)reLoadCalendarObject
{
if (self.calViewController != nil)
    self.calViewController = nil;   //release instantiated object

CalViewController *tempCalViewController = [[CalViewController alloc]initWithDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.0f] observer:self];
self.calViewController = tempCalViewController;
[tempCalViewController release];
self.calViewController.dataSource = self.calendarDataSource;
}
```

`self.calViewController` property is declared as `(nonatomic,retain)`

Comment: What makes you think it might cause a memory leak? ... this is fine

Comment: Because I thought you have to use the 'release' keyword to actually release an object from memory, just like this is happening in dealloc.

Comment: Run it in Instruments to see if it's creating a leak.

Comment: @Oysio if you `@synthesize` an `@property` with `retain` the compiler puts the correct memory management in the synthesized getters and setters. In this case the setter would correctly release the old value and set the ivar to `nil`

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091394/is-setting-a-property-to-nil-same-as-releasing-the-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@property (nonatomic, retain) MyObject *myObject;` and `@synthesize myObject = _myObject;` the compiler will generate the getters and setters for you. The setter will **behave** (not necessarily be implemented like this) something like this

```
1| - (void)setMyObject:(MyObject *)myObject;
2| {
3|     if (_myObject != myObject) {
4|         [_myObject release];
5|         _myObject = [myObject retain];
6|     }
7| }
```

At line **3** we do a check to make sure that the object you are setting is not the same object as the one passed in (we check the pointer as we are checking it is the exact same object)

At line **4** we know we have different objects so we need to release the old value

At line **5** we take a retain to the new object

---

As @thesaad pointed out your `self.calViewController = nil;` is superflous and so to in fact is the `if (self.calViewController 1= nil)` as it would be perfectly safe to send `nil` (or any object) if the property is already set.

In you example of passing `nil` this is what happens.

At line **3** we see that `nil` is not the same object as one that is previously set

At line **4** we release the old object

At line **5** we set the backing ivar to `nil`. Calling `retain` on `nil` is a no-op so that's fine as well

Answer (score 0):

these lines are extra in your code.

```
if (self.calViewController != nil)
    self.calViewController = nil;   //release instantiated object
```

when you make a property then memory management goes to compiler end. and the way you are  re instantiating it is perfact. so the code will be likse this

```
- (void)reLoadCalendarObject
{


CalViewController *tempCalViewController = [[CalViewController alloc]initWithDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.0f] observer:self];
self.calViewController = tempCalViewController;
[tempCalViewController release];
self.calViewController.dataSource = self.calendarDataSource;
}
```